# Change parameters used in function to be applied to dataframe

Tags: python, function, pandas

I would like to apply a function to a dataframe, but change the parameters used in that function. I want to:

- assign the parameters (each row of the parameters_df) to be used in the calculation
- perform the calculation using the parameters as inputs
- calculate some summary inform from that round of calculation (mean score in this example) and record this in the parameters dataframe
- repeat the above process using the next line of parameters from the parameters_df

My actual code is more complicated with many more parameters and a more complicated calculation with a variety of outputs, but this shows the principle:

```
>>> parameters_df # these are the parameters that I want to loop through
a   b   c  mean_output # (this is what I want to calculate)
1   2   3
1   3   5

>>> calc_df
name  category  score   # output(this is what I want to calculate)
John  a           50  
Jill  c           60
Jenny b           70
Jeff  a           80
```

This is my code:

```
def set_parameters(row):
    parameter_dict = {a: row['a'], 1:row['b'], 2:row['c']}
    parameter_df['output'] = parameter_df.apply(calc, axis=1)
    return parameter_df['output'].mean(axis = 1)

def calc(row):
    output = parameter_dict[row['parameter_df']] * 2
    return output

parameters_df['mean_score'] = parameters_df.apply(set_parameters, axis = 1)
```

But I get this error code:

> ("name 'parameter_dict' is not defined", 'occurred at index 0', 'occurred at index 0')

It's like when performing the calc function, it cannot find the parameters dictionary I have defined in set_parameters function, even though the set parameters uses calc function in its calculation.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing the variable between the two functions.  You need to:

```
def set_parameters(row):
    parameter_dict = {a: row['a'], 1:row['b'], 2:row['c']}
    parameter_df['output'] = parameter_df.apply(calc, args=(parameter_dict,), axis=1)
    return parameter_df['output'].mean(axis = 1)

def calc(row, parameter_dict):
    output = parameter_dict[row['parameter_df']] * 2
    return output
```